# How can I set a target to top for a link within an iframe?

Tags: jquery

in my code for index.html I use jQuery and have a link with id #button3.

I have used in index.html

```
 $('#button3 a').attr({
                            target: '_top'
                        });
```

When I call the index.html from an iframe as a src, the page opens in _self. 
I have tried with _blank and still when clicking on the a link it doesn't open on a new page.

I have this code

```
 //handle click OK button
                $("#button3").click(function(){
                    if (validate()) {
                        submitQuery();
                    }
                });

                        //set the target attribut to return to the parent

                       $('#button3 a').attr('target', '_parent');
```

and 2 functions validate and submitQuery don't call the a link at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct set-attribute syntax is:

```
$('#button3 a').attr('target', '_top');
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, I have tried that and it doesn't work. I have even tried on the main index.html button with no luck

Comment: See if you have the correct element, try putting a border on it:
$('#button3 a').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');

Comment: @Diodeus, I appreciate your help. It still doesn't happen. I have other jquery code in the same page. Can this cause any issues?
If you would like I can provide you with a link if you don't mind in PM. 
Thanks

Comment: hmm, couldn't find any PM system on stackoverflow!!